# How do I access a second sub-element within a list and pass it to *apply?

Tags: r, lapply, r-caret

Given a list (`list.data.partitions`) with 72 elements (`dataset_1`, `dataset_2`, etc.), each of which contain two sub-elements (2 dataframes):`$training` and `$testing`; e.g.:

```
> str(list.data.partitions$dataset_1)
List of 2
 $ training:'data.frame':   81 obs. of  20 variables:
  ..$ b0   : num [1:81] 11.61 9.47 10.61 7.34 12.65 ...
  ..$ b1   : num [1:81] 11.6 9.94 10.7 10.11 12.2 ...
  ..$ b2   : num [1:81] 34.2 31 32.7 27.9 36.1 ...
  ...
  ..$ index: num [1:81] 0.165 0.276 0.276 0.181 0.201 ...

 $ testing :'data.frame':   19 obs. of  20 variables:
  ..$ b0   : num [1:19] 6.05 12.4 13.99 16.82 8.8 ...
  ..$ b1   : num [1:19] 12.4 10.8 11.8 13.7 16.3 ...
  ..$ b2   : num [1:19] 25.4 29.8 31.2 34.1 27.3 ...
  ...
  ..$ index: num [1:19] 0.143 1.114 0.201 0.529 1.327 ...
```

How would I correctly access the `$testing` dataframe using lapply (or similar functionality) and caret's `predict` function below:

```
    fun.predict.rf <- function(x, y) {
      predict(x, newdata = y$testing)
    }

    list.predictions <- lapply(list.models, fun.predict.rf, y=list.data.partitions)
```

The above function "works", but it returns predictions based on `$training` dataframe (~80 obs), instead of the `$testing` dataframe (~20 obs) that was specified. Ultimately, I'd expect a list containing predictions for each of the elements in my list, based on the `$testing` dataframe.

`list.models` is a list of 72 models based on the `$training` dataframe using the `caret` package in R (not shown or included). The number of models (72) in `list.models` equals the number of elements (72) in `list.data.partitions` when considering a single sub-element (either `$training` or `$testing`). The name of each of the 72 elements in `list.data.partitions` differs like so: `dataset_1`, `dataset_2`, etc., but the structure is identical (see `str` output above).

`list.data.partitions` can be downloaded [here](http://filebin.ca/1cHVeR9ayOX5). In this version, the 72 elements do not have names, but in my version the 72 elements are named (e.g., `dataset_1`, `dataset_2`, etc). Each of the sub-elements are still named `$training` and `$testing`.

Comment: Doesn't your call need to have `y=list.data.partitions$dataset_1` rather than `y=list.data.partitions`?  That's why it's not working. I am unable to extract the data from that file, btw

Comment: I see what you're driving at, but if I hard code `y=list.data.partitions$dataset_1` into the call, then each of the 72 models in `model.list` would call that specific dataset, whereas I want each of the models to run on the `$testing` dataframe of each element. Something like `list.data.partitions$[each of the 72 elements]$testing` is what I want, but I can't find the right syntax. I used `save(list.data.partitions, file = "/file/path")` to save the object, so it probably has to be loaded into R.

Comment: I've changed my answer. I think it will be better now

Comment: I may be wrong, but it seems the simplest solution here is to use `mapply`.  If you change your function call to: `list.predictions <- mapply(fun.predict.rf, list.models, list.data.partitions)`, I think you should get the desired result.

Comment: @Cotton.Rockwood - uhh...damn. That works and it's simple. Can you write up that answer and why it works as opposed to using lapply?

Comment: Written up below.  Glad I could help.  You should check out the difference between `mapply` and `lapply`.  If you are working from one list, `lapply` is your tool.  If you have multiple lists and you want to access each of the corresponding elements in each list, `mapply` is needed. Again, an alternative to using `mapply` here would be to create the model objects as a third item in your `list.data.partitons` elements.  Then you can use the simple approach @Steven mentions.

Comment: @RichardScriven - I disagree. If you read the question, it's quite clear as to what I'm asking. I clearly state the desired results and have provided the actual dataset as requested. No need to be so cross. That said, put your answer back in and I'll upvote it, because as you said, you put a lot of work into answering the question; however, I don't think it's the best answer. The `mapply` functionality is much more succinct, and answers my question most directly with the least amount of modification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the simple solution is to use `mapply` instead of `lapply`.  Alternatively, you could store the model objects in the same list with the `training` and `testing` data sets and use `lapply` as suggested by Steven.  Using a modified version of Richard Scriven's example data set with your list names:

```
set.seed(1)
dataset <- list(training = data.frame(replicate(4, rnorm(10))),
                testing = data.frame(replicate(4, rexp(5))))
dataset1 <- list(training = data.frame(replicate(4, rnorm(10))),
                 testing = data.frame(replicate(4, rexp(5))))
dataset2 <- list(training = data.frame(replicate(4, rnorm(10))),
                testing = data.frame(replicate(4, rexp(5))))
list.data.partitions <- c(replicate(2, dataset, simplify = FALSE),list(dataset1), list(dataset2))
names(list.data.partitions) <- paste0("dataset", seq(list.data.partitions))
```

This gives a list with two identical data sets followed by two unique data sets for explanatory purposes.
Then, creating your model object list with a basic linear fit:

```
list.models <- lapply(list.data.partitions, function(x) lm(X1 ~ X2+X3+X4, data = x$training))
```

With these two objects, use `mapply`:

```
fun.predict.rf <- function(x, y) {
     predict(x, newdata = y$testing)
 }

list.predictions <- mapply(fun.predict.rf, list.models, list.data.partitions)
list.predictions

      dataset1     dataset2    dataset3   dataset4
1 -0.098696452 -0.098696452  0.09015207 -0.5004038
2  0.103316974  0.103316974  0.11770013 -0.7323202
3 -0.908623491 -0.908623491 -0.06951799 -0.8765770
4 -1.332241452 -1.332241452 -0.20407761 -0.5816534
5 -0.002156741 -0.002156741 -0.24583670 -0.7057936
```

Note that the first two data sets have identical predictions as we would expect and there are five predicted elements for each dataset, consistent with the number of testing elements.

I think there was some confusion because it was not clear in your question that your model objects were stored in a separate list (`list.models`).  Since you were passing `lapply` your `list.models` but specifying `y=list.data.partitions`, your function `fun.predict.rf` was being passed each model element sequentially, but your entire `list.data.partitions` with each call.  There is no element `list.data.partitions$testing`, so you were actually specifying `newdata = NULL`, so the predict function ignored the `newdata` argument and used the data from the model object.  Notice, if you use your `lapply` code and compare to predictions for individual training elements, they match:

```
list.predictions <- lapply(list.models, fun.predict.rf, y=list.data.partitions)
list.predictions

predict(model.list[[1]], newdata=list.data.partitions[[1]]$training)
predict(model.list[[2]], newdata=list.data.partitions[[2]]$training)
predict(model.list[[3]], newdata=list.data.partitions[[3]]$training)
predict(model.list[[4]], newdata=list.data.partitions[[4]]$training)
```

And if you change the data in the `list.data.partitions`, the `lapply` call still gives the same result while specifying the `list.data.partitions$training` data gives a different result:

```
list.data.partitions[[1]] <- list.data.partitions[[3]]
lapply(list.models, fun.predict.rf, y=list.data.partitions)

predict(list.models[[1]], newdata=list.data.partitions[[1]]$training)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can declare function within apply.

After I read the question carefully, this might work.
Let's assume you got the following data structure

```
list.data.partitions
  ..$dataset_1
    ..$training
    ..$testing
    ..$model # model created using the caret package

  ..$dataset_2
    ..$training
    ..$testing
    ..$model # model created using the caret package
```

Let's add $model to the dataset, since it one-to-one relationship. It make sense to keep them together. I assuming you build the model from $training, and going to test on $test.

```
for(i in 1:len(list.data.partitions){
  list.data.partitions[[i]]$model <- list.models[[i]]
}
```

Assuming dataset 1 and 2 are not related, and each dataset got 3 elements (training, testing, model from training, more on this later)

```
fun.predict.rf <- function(x, y) {
      predict(x, newdata = y)
}
lapply(list.data.partitions, function(x){

  #something like
  #if no model exist yet, then you can create it here with x$training
  result<- fun.predict.rf(x$model, x$testing)
  #other things you want to do

})
```

Comment: `fun.predict.rf(x)` isn't defined in your answer. Also, I'm not entirely clear why `output` would be composed of both `training` and `testing`. I just want to use the latter. Can you provide more detail?

Comment: There's no `$model` sub-element, just `$training` and `$testing`. Models are stored in a list called `model.list`, which is called by `lapply`.